# Npm bundled dependencies not working as expected

Tags: node.js, npm

I am using node 14 with npm 6 where the `bundledDependencies` should be supported.

I am trying to have this setup:

- package-C is the bundled dependency of package-B
- package-B is the dependency of package-A

then I expect I can use APIs exposed by package-C when developing package-A **without** having package-C as the dependency or devDependency in package-A's `package.json`.

However, this is not working as `require.resolve("package-C")` throws "Cannot find module" error under package-A.

Then I check the `package-lock.json` of package-A and I don't see any dependencies listed under package-B entry (I am trying to check if package-B -> package-C has `bundled` set as `true` or not).

```
{
  "name": "package-A",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 1,
  "requires": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "package-B": {
      "version": "1.0.0"
      // I am wishing to see something like the following but there is not:
      // "dependencies": {
      //   "package-C": {
      //     "version": "1.0.0",
      //     "bundled": true
      //   }
      // }
    }
  }
}
```

During the `npm pack` of package-B, however, I do see the following output indicating package-C being bundled:

```
npm notice
npm notice   package-B
npm notice === Tarball Contents ===
npm notice redacted
npm notice === Bundled Dependencies ===
npm notice package-C
npm notice === Tarball Details ===
npm notice name:          package-B
npm notice version:       1.0.0
npm notice package size:  17.7 MB
npm notice unpacked size: 127.5 MB
npm notice shasum:        redacted
npm notice integrity:     redacted
npm notice bundled deps:  1
npm notice bundled files: 4142
npm notice own files:     18
npm notice total files:   4160
npm notice
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

I did more experiments and below are my findings:

- bundling of a dependency (package-C) in a package (package-B) does not make the bundled dependency (package-C) available for the dependant package (package-A)
- bundled package (package-C) is only available to which package (package-B) it is bundled
- the purpose of bundling is to make a locally modified dependency (package-C, which is not generally available from NPM registry via an `npm install`) available to the bundling package (package-B) when it is used by the dependant package (package-A)

My attempt of bring in transitive dependencies via a dependency using `bundledDependencies` is wrong from the very beginning as it is not supported at all.