# Sharing dependencies and their versions across a large number of npm packages

Tags: node.js, npm, dependency-management

We have a large number of npm packages, namely package-A ... package-Z, which are independent packages (ie. which are **not** packages within the same monorepo).

All these packages have a set of common `dependencies` and `devDependencies` of the same versions. Currently those dependencies are explicitly declared in the package.json file of all the packages.

As you can see, dependency management for these packages is a nightmare:

- updating the version of a specific common dependency requires changes to all of their package.json
- adding a new dependency also requires changes to all the their package.json

In order to ease out the painful dependency management, I attempted to create a single package which has all the common dependencies bundled (ie. having the common dependencies declared in the `bundledDependencies`), and then have those package-A ... package-Z depend on the new package.

However, this approach is proved to be not working as asked and self-answered in another recently raised question: [Npm bundled dependencies not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71367085/990106).

Is there a better way to handle the dependency management across different packages?

Comment: I found a tool for package.json inheritance (https://github.com/Cosium/dry-dry) of which idea sounds promising, however, it is not under active development or maintenance.